# Using apostrophes in names in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Problem:**

I have a spreadsheet with tabs and formulae that derive from proper names. I'm running into problems running an apps script where the proper name includes apostrophes.

**Goal:**

I want to be able to keep the apostrophes in names without causing spreadsheet chaos.

**Attempted solutions:**

I was able to fix the syntax for the sheet tabs by replacing ' punctuation with ", as follows:

Example 1 (wrong):

```
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('O'Brien requests page'), true);
```

Fix for Ex. 1:

```
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("O'Brien requests page"), true);
```

However, I can't seem to get it right for *search terms* and *set values* in formulae. I've tried using two consecutive ' marks instead of ", which I saw on a previous answer, but that only produced an error. The same thing happened when I replaced all single ' marks with ", so that's no help in this case. These are the two formulae where I'm lost:

**Still stuck:**

Example 2 (still wrong):

```
spreadsheet.getRange('B6').setFormula('=iferror(query(\'Contact list\'!A6:F,"Select A,B,C,D where C=\'O'Brien, Conan\'",0),"None")');
```

Example 3 (still wrong):

```
spreadsheet.getRange('D3').setFormula('=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((NOT(ISBLANK(A3:A))),"O'Keefe",""))');
```

How do I fix this without demanding that people change their names? Thank you!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. I think that `Example 2 (still wrong):` can be modified. But, I cannot understand the issue of `Example 3 (still wrong):`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I forgot to mark that as O'Keefe. Fixed it now, so that one fails, too.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
spreadsheet.getRange('B6').setFormula('=iferror(query(\'Contact list\'!A6:F,"Select A,B,C,D where C=\'O'Brien, Conan\'",0),"None")');

spreadsheet.getRange('D3').setFormula('=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((NOT(ISBLANK(A3:A))),"O'Keefe",""))');
```

#### To:

```
const formula1 = `=iferror(query('Contact list'!A6:F,"Select A,B,C,D where C=""O'Brien, Conan""",0),"None")`;
spreadsheet.getRange('B6').setFormula(formula1);

const formula2 = `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((NOT(ISBLANK(A3:A))),"""O'Keefe""",""))`;
spreadsheet.getRange('D3').setFormula(formula2);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was almost perfect. In the second example, though, I found that changing from: 

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((NOT(ISBLANK(A3:A))),"""O'Keefe""","")) 

to 

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((NOT(ISBLANK(A3:A))),"O'Keefe","")) 

actually worked better, because it didn't leave quotation marks around the name in the cell. But still, thank you so much for getting me there!
PS - If anyone needs the same thing with a filter command, the syntax would be:

const formula3 = `=iferror(filter('Contact list'!A6:C,'Contact list'!D6:D="O'Keefe"),"None")`; spreadsheet.getRange('J6').setFormula(formula3);